# Volume of solid revolution 2

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

Let R be the be the limited area in the first quadrant that's above the curve $ y = x^2$ and below the curve $y = 8 - x$. Determine the volume when it's rotated around the y-axis.

The problem for me here is that it's rotated around the y-axis. Otherwise I could just have used the function $\int_0^2 \pi (8-x)^2 - \pi (x^2)^2$ but that doesn't work here.

How do I tackle problems like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wanted solid of revolution is given by the union of a cone and a parabolic cap:

[image]

Since $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r = \frac{n^2}{2}+O(n)$ and $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^2 = \frac{n^3}{3}+O(n^2)$ we have that the volume of the cone is $\frac{1}{3}\pi R^2 h_1$ and the volume of the parabolic cap is $\frac{1}{2}\pi R^2 h_2$. Since the graphs of $y=8-x$ and $y=x^2$ meet at $\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{33}}{2},\frac{17-\sqrt{33}}{2}\right)$ in the first quadrant, we have $R=h_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{33}}{2}$ and $h_2=\frac{17-\sqrt{33}}{2}$, so the wanted volume is
$$ V = \frac{\pi}{12}\left(33\sqrt{33}-433\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for $x,y\geq 0$, you may invert both functions to find 
$$
x=y-8\\
x=\sqrt{y}
$$
and proceed with your usual methods.

Comment: So I should do this $ \int_0^2 \pi (y-8)^2 - \pi (\sqrt {y})^2 $ ?

Comment: you will have to split it up into two integrals if you want to do the washer method

Comment: So $ \int_0^2 \pi (y-8)^2 -  \pi \int_0^2 (\sqrt {y})^2 $?